# JCS Cache shutdown,guaranteed persistence to disk

Tags: java, performance, caching, concurrency, jcs

Iam using JCS for caching.Now I am using disk cache to temporarily store all the data.The problem is when I use JCS,the keys are written to disk only if the cache is properly shutdown.

I am using the disk usage pattern as UPDATE which tells JCS to immediately write data to the disk without keeping it in memory.But the problem is we are not maitaining the key list of objects in the cache.So I use group cache access and get the keys from the cache and then iterate through the keys to get the results.

So now I am caught in a situation where I have to shutdown the cache properly i.e after all the data is written to disk using Indexed disk cache.But there is a complexity here,the indexed disk cache uses a background thread to write to disk which does not return anything on its status.

So now,I am unable to guarantee that indexed disk cache has written data to the disk to my front end implementation.Is there a way to tackle this situation,because now I am just sleeping some random time(say 10 seconds),before the cache is shutdown,which is a very stupid way of doing it actually.

Edit : I am facing this issue with Memory Cache as well,but a sleep of one second is mostly enough for 500mb of data.But the case of disk cache is little different.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because your objects are stored in the memory and waiting to write to disk. If you need to write the objects immediately to disk while in execution then you need to make the `MaxObjects` of your cache configs to `0`.

`jcs.region.<yourRegion>.cacheattributes.MaxObjects=0
jcs.region.<yourRegion>.cacheattributes.DiskUsagePattern=UPDATE`

I know you already aware of `UPDATE`. Adding it for reference again.